# I think my question have been wrongly closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request, close-reasons, moderation

I don't understand the argument on why the mod closed my question: [AMD Radeon HD 7000 cards that do not use more than the total bandwidth of PCI-E 2.0](https://superuser.com/questions/550397/amd-radeon-hd-7000-cards-that-do-not-use-more-than-the-total-bandwidth-of-pci-e)

Small geographic area? I think my question could be understood by anyone in the world with expertise in graphics hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Small geographic area" is only one way a question can be "too localized". The core of that close reason is really that the question is unlikely to help other people -- it's specific to your individual situation. In that case, I assume the issue is that "Radeon 7000, PCIe 2" is specific to right now ("too localized" in time, not space). It also seems dangerously close to hardware recommendations (which are explicitly off-topic on all SE sites, partly because they are very time-specific). If you made the question more general (e.g., by asking about how to tell if a card uses too much bandwidth, or what the consequences of that are), it might be less likely to be closed.

Comment: Yes, precisely - OP focused on the geographic area, while it's very close to a product recommendation & the focus on 7000 series makes it heavily specific & localized